Whenever I record or listen with earphones, there is a constant sound that can be heard
I have noticed a weird constant sound that can be heard when wearing earphones or headphones, it's really faint but can be heard.
It's not a buzzing sound or static sound. It's something electric type.
It can also be heard when recording it with any mic. Here is the link of my drive where I have uploaded a recording from my newest mic.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Afhaw3Q4FP24PTkWDy5MIITwz2QBB_da/view?usp=drivesdk

It's really faint so try to listen it with earphones with max volume. That sound you will hear is not the sound of my PC fans, my mic cannot capture it because it has active noise cancellation but it cannot cancel that werid faint sound
Every USB thing is new, sound capture card is new, mic is new, usb hub is new, everything is new but still this sound can be heard.
I have posted question like this long ago but no one gave me any answer.

google videos for "ground loop recording" and compare. If this is the problem, post your solution as an answer

Also, test with other equipment. Even brand new equipment can have a fault, or what you hear is just in the design of this particular equipment.

It's not a grounding issue. If it changes pitch or intensity depending on what your computer is doing, then it's likely to be an RF-induced interference in the analog side of the audio circuitry. If it remains fairly constant, then it's just a poor noise floor, usually caused by cheap components.
If it really bothers you, consider getting a higher quality external DAC.

This is the likely issue. It's not even limited to cheap computers or phones or other electronic devices. The majority of electronic and digital devices simply do not prioritize protecting and isolating the components that handle sound. Purpose-built media systems are were you are more likely to find sound circuits isolated from the rest of the system in a way that will avoid this hum. Certain LG cell phones use a high quality DAC, and some Gigabyte mainboards physically isolate the sound components. Otherwise, you'll need to use a dedicated audio device.

I found the problem, it's definitely ground loop. I guess i have to buy group loop insulator which is cheap for you guys but not for me, anyways thanks for telling me the problem I was so frustrated with this problem

It doesn't sound like ground loop. I normalised it so I could listen properly loud. Ground loop is usually a 50 or 60Hz hum [with harmonic overtones]. there's a possibility it's RFI from a switch-mode power supply - which might make you think of ground loop as it would stop if you were running on battery not mains.

Is there is a possibility of power supply doing that? The power supply is like 4 to 5 years old so maybe power supply is doing something power related? Also there is earthing issue in house too but not the problematic. Tell me what's the problem

FWIW Whenever I have a ground loop issue it is very loud with respect to any audio signal. I cannot eve hear it in your recording but I am not in a place where I can listen properly. If the earphones are the typical earbud style, then the very thin cabling often acts as an antenna and can pick up e.g. HDD noise

I didn't get my answer that i recently asked, can a 5 years old power supply is the problem of that faint noise?

The age is irrelevant. It's the design of both the power supply & the computer itself.
